# Win32: How to post message to a process run by a different user in Windows?

Tags: winapi, ipc, inter-process-communicat, window-messages, interprocess

We run two application, each of them register the same message using RegisterWindowMessage(): application A as a regular user and application B as administrator in the same user's session on the machine, and those applications would send this message one to another.
When A and B were run as a same user everything was fine and we were able to communicate using PostMessage() messaging. Now as application B is run as administrator messages do not come through any more. What can we do about it?

Does this situation mandate us to use other mechanisms (other than messages)?

Comment: Kernel namespaces do not apply to window messages.

Comment: Why not use other kind of IPC?

Comment: @rkosegi Just didn't want to recode what already has been coded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Windows Vista and later, [User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vishalsi/archive/2006/11/30/what-is-user-interface-privilege-isolation-uipi-on-vista.aspx) prevents a lower integrity process from sending window messages to a higher integrity process.  In earlier Windows versions, malicious code could attack administrative processes by misusing window messages.  By default, UIPI blocks all messages with a value above `WM_USER`, which includes messages registered via `RegisterWindowMessage()`.  So, in order to allow A to send such messages to B, B must first call [`ChangeWindowMessageFilter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632675.aspx) or [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388202.aspx) for each blocked message that it wants to receive from lower integrity processes.